# Extraction by mask using a polygon changes the cell counts on each category?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, extract-by-mask, cell-size

I am attempting to use Extraction by Mask on a raster set (land use) to gather the cell counts of each category. The data is from a county level and the polygon I am using is a specific city within that county. When I use the tool, the resulting raster set shows cell count values that are way higher than the original set (making it seem like the area is somehow larger). This does not make sense to me as it does not change the size of each cell (2.5, 2.5) or the linear unit (feet) of the resulting raster.

Is there something that I am missing?

I have tried various methods to bypass this issue and extract the cell counts of the raster within the polygon, but each results in the same outcome. I have exhausted all of my knowledge and am probably just missing something. I can provide screenshots later if this does not make sense.

Comment: What happens when you export entire raster?

Comment: Build the raster attribute table http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m2000000 for both rasters, one of them is wrong, rebuilding should fix the one that is incorrect.